# UITableViewCell text alignment when mixing accessory views

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, text-alignment

I've got a custom background image on a UITableViewCell. I've got the text centered in that cell. On certain rows, I've got the *UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton* set to indiciate there are details for that row.

However, using that accessory type causes the text to shift to the left, but my background image stays central. Is there a way I can add some padding to the label inside the tablecell to push the text back into the middle, so it lines up with the other rows.

I understand that adding an accessory makes the content view smaller, and so it is still technically centered, but I need it to match the others.

[image: Mixture of accessory type button and none, and misaligned text]

Comment: I've temporarily fixed this by adding a 25x25 pixel image to the image view, as in **cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spacer.png"]**, this feels cheeky and wrong but it works for now. Any sensible suggestions are still welcome

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty view of the correct size (not sure what that is ... 20x20?) and set the `accessoryView` to it.

Comment: Are you suggesting I add an empty accessory view to the other rows? So **P13TTE** in the screen shot above. That would just make all the rows off center

Comment: Ah. My bad. I was thinking of getting them to line up rather than to center them. I can think of a number of ways of fixing this but they'd all involve a custom table cell with an overloaded `layoutSubviews` ... There may be a better approach.

Comment: I think I need to use a custom frame on the label, so I'll need to use a subclassed UITableViewCell I guess. I've tried adding a blank image to the left side of the cell, but it was a bit dirty and was hard to lign up properly anyway